# Hide Slack's new "Shortcuts" bar?

Tags: user-interface, slack

I work in two different slack workspaces, ... one has updated to the new UI, and one has not. I really do not like this new shortcuts bar in the new workspace, highlighted in the red box in the below screenshot.

Is there any way to turn that bar off? It simply takes up space, leaving less room for reading messages and viewing the channel/messages, list, and it provides utterly **zero** additional value to the UI or to navigation that wasn't already there.

I've searched the slack docs, the preferences section, and the list of slack questions here, but can't seem to find anything.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, it isn't *exactly* what I was looking to do, but I found a workaround.

As per this github thread, I enabled Slack developer mode.
https://gist.github.com/Kenny-MWI/6b1a88ad38b5ffef347527a82becf054#windows-enable-dev-mode

Once I did that, and restarted Slack, I then got a button to hide the Workspace switcher. This made the "Home" button the workspace switcher, so at least now I'm back down to just one "button bar" instead of two... thus reclaiming the extra space.

It works at least; would still prefer to get rid of all those stupid buttons, but this is good enough.

[image]

[image]